# how to evaulate 2 queries output data into one with dual

Tags: sql, oracle

how to evaulate 2 queries output data into one  with dual.

Can  i do like below?, but is giving error saying statusB not found.

```
 select case when (statusA is NULL or statusA ='N') and (statusB is NULL or statusB ='N') then 'N'
   else 'Y' from 
   (
     select statusA from test
     union
     select statusB from test1
   ) dual;
```

Trying to evaluate below table

```
 statusA from table1       statusB from table2                     Result
  Y                          null or no data                         Y
  N                          null or no data                         N
null or no data                 Y                                    Y
null or no data                 N                                    N 
  Y                             Y                                    Y
  Y                             N                                    Y
  null                        null                                   N 
  N                             N                                    N
```

Regards,
chaituhara

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

When you `union` two result sets the column names in the combined set are taken from the first branch of the union. You've effectively got:

```
select statusA from test
union
select statusB as statusA from test1
```

So there is no `statusB` to work with in the result set. You maybe want to do something like:

```
select case when (select nvl(max(statusA), 'N') from test) = 'N'
  and (select nvl(max(statusB), 'N') from test1) = 'N'
  then 'N' else 'Y' end
from dual
```

Though I'm not quite sure if you expect a single value from each table, and quite what you're trying to do.

---

OK then, with an ID value linking the two tables, and with a given ID being in one or both of the tables, you can use a full outer join:

```
select coalesce(t.id, t1.id) as id, t.statusa, t1.statusb,
  case when nvl(statusa, 'N') = 'N' and nvl(statusb, 'N') = 'N'
    then 'N' else 'Y' end as flag
from test t
full outer join test1 t1 on t1.id = t.id
order by coalesce(t.id, t1.id);
```

With the values you added to the question - and assuming that 'no data' means no matching row in that table for an ID that exists in the other one - that gives you:

```
        ID STATUSA STATUSB FLAG
---------- ------- ------- ----
         1 Y               Y    
         2 N               N    
         3         Y       Y    
         4         N       N    
         5 Y       Y       Y    
         6 Y       N       Y    
         7                 N    
         8 N       N       N
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0e52/1).

Comment: i want single result based on my data.

Comment: You have at most one row in each table though, right? I've added `max()` to deal with there being no rows. I think that handles all your scenarios?

Comment: sorry ,i want to retrieve id associated with each record.if query returns 2 values ,each status refere to one id like 1 N,2 Y etc..

Comment: @user2750658 - I'm still not sure I fully understand what you need, but I've added a version that gets the result you showed in your question edit.

Answer (score 0):

LET your table testa be:

```
id  statusa
1   Y
2   N
3   null or no data
4   null or no data
5   Y
6   Y
7   
8   N
```

and the table testb:

```
id      statusb
1   null or no data
2   null or no data
3   Y
4   N
5   Y
6   N
7   
8   N
```

now you can:

```
SELECT STATUSA, STATUSB,  CASE WHEN new_statusa  = 'Y' OR new_statusb = 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END RESULT
FROM
(SELECT STATUSA, STATUSB, CASE WHEN statusa IS NOT NULL AND statusa <> 'Y' THEN 'N' ELSE nvl(STATUSa,'N') END new_statusa,
     case when statusB is not null and statusB <> 'Y' THEN 'N' ELSE nvl(STATUSB,'N') end new_statusb
FROM TESTa
JOIN testb USING (id));
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your original query there, its easy enough to alias statusa and statusb columns in the union.  Note, I added each column then union all instead of union and removed the dual alias as that is an Oracle reserved "dummy table".

```
 select case when (statusA is NULL or statusA ='N') and (statusB is NULL or statusB ='N') then 'N'
   else 'Y' from 
   (
     select statusA, null as statusB from test
     union all
     select null as statusA, statusB from test1
   ) ;
```